# What are words that are spelt the same but pronounced differently?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation, heteronyms

Words like *"read"*, *"wind"*, *"live"* and *"lead"* are spelt the same, but have different meanings:

> Lead<sup>1</sup> (leed):
>   cause (a person or animal) to go with one by holding them by the hand, a halter, a rope, etc. while moving forward.
>   -- [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lead)

and

> Lead<sup>2</sup> (led):
>   A heavy, comparatively soft, malleable, bluish-grey metal.
>   -- [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lead)

So what are these words called? And are there any others, beside the 4 I have mentioned?

Comment: They are called homographs, and you could add bear (hairy animal; carry) or sow (lady pig; scatter seeds) to the list.

Comment: @RoaringFish those are examples of words that are spelt the same but also are pronounced the same... the OP requested words that are spelt the same but pronounced differently

Comment: No, like *bow* (curtsey / ribbon) - pronounced differently, or *tear* (rip / cry).

Comment: Bow actually has three the two you stated and also the weapon

Comment: @Nathan But bow the weapon is pronounced the same as bow the ribbon.

Comment: I know but its a different example I guess

Comment: @NathanTaylor ~ a lady pig rhymes with cow, scattering seeds rhymes with show. The two bears sound the same but it is still a homograph as the meaning is different.

Comment: @RoaringFish Ah so in that case Sow is a Heteronym and Bear is a Homograph?

Comment: Yes, sort of. *Sow* is a heteronym and a homograph, but *bear* is just a homograph as the sound is the same but the meaning is different. I didn't suggest heteronym as that includes present simple/past simple pairs such a *read* and *lead* which change sound but not spelling when they are used in the past tense. That appears to me to be the same meaning with a different tense, but looking at the OP he does suggest *read* as an example.

Comment: @NathanTaylor *Sow* is a heteronym and a homograph. *Bear* is just a homograph. So I believe ...

Comment: @terdon _This question_ also specifies that they should be pronounced differently.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and there I go, jumping to conclusions again. So it does indeed. Comments removed, closevote added.

Comment: But unlike the earlier question, this question also asks for examples of such words (not that such examples are especially difficult to find once you know what they are called).

Comment: Yes, maybe they could be merged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Word that are spelled the same, but  which have different meanings and etymologies are normally referred to as:

- homographs

Words that are spelled the same but pronounced differently are:

- heteronyms

The word homograph is made from two morphemes. The first is *homo-* meaning *same*. The second is *graph* which means writing or *written*. *-nym* as you can probably guess means *name*.

Other examples of homographs:

- (river) bank, (high street bank)
- (transport) plane (woodwork tool)
- (person) fan (machine)
- (implement) pen (farm)
- (punctuation) colon (pooh)

Some heteronyms  - which are also homographs:

- (argue) row (sport)
- (guitar) bass (fish)
- (genuflect) bow (ribbon)
- (wind) buffet (canape)

Answer (score 5):

HOMONYMS are words that **sound alike but have different meanings**.

Homophones are a type of homonym that also sound alike and have different meanings, but have different spellings.

HOMOGRAPHS are words that are **spelled the same but have different meanings**.

Heteronyms are a type of homograph that are also spelled the same and have different meanings, but sound different.

[image: For simplification:]

Answer (score 4):

Words that are spelled the same but are pronounced differently are call *Heteronyms*

For an interesting article on word types, see  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some additional examples of heteronyms (many of them lifted from [this site](http://richard.tangle-wood.co.uk/heteronym.html)):

- (second option) *alternate* (switch back and forth)
- (suitable) *appropriate* (commandeer)
- (panel) *console* (comfort)
- (complete, v) *consummate* (perfect, adj.)
- (satisfied) *content* (thing or things contained)
- (document, n) *contract* (shrink)
- (talk, v) *converse* (thing reversed in order)
- (representative) *delegate* (assign)
- (intentional) *deliberate* (consider carefully)
- (price reduction) *discount* (minimize or disregard)
- (way in) *entrance* (enrapture or enthrall)
- (very close) *intimate* (suggest indirectly)
- (incorrect) *invalid* (disabled)
- (frown) *lower* (relative position)
- (60 seconds) *minute* (tiny)
- (temperate) *moderate* (preside or oversee)
- (in attendance) *present* (give)
- (undercoat paint) primer (textbook)
- (fruits and vegetables) *produce* (generate)
- (advance, n) *progress* (advance, v)
- (tell) *recount* (add again)
- (deny) *refuse* (garbage)
- (move apart) *separate* (distinct)
- (have doubts about) *suspect* (person under suspicion)
- (carry as freight) *transport* (conveyance)
- (distress or discombobulate) *upset* (surprise victory)

There are many, many others.